# Знакомство с каналами

Tags: golang

Ранее никогда не работал с каналами так как не было нужды, сейчас же всё поменялось, нужна многопоточность, и я подумал что в этом случае каналы будут очень хороши. Я хочу запускать функцию `handleMessage()` в новой горутине, и когда я буду отправлять какое-то сообщение в канал, функция `handleMessage()` должна это обрабатывать, функция `handleMessage()` должна работать в бесконечном цикле.

Должно быть что-то такое, но это не работает:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func handleMessage(msg chan string) {
    for {
        select {
        // We caught message.
        case m := <-msg:
            fmt.Println(m)
        }
    }
}

func main() {
    mchan := make(chan string)
    go handleMessage(mchan)

    // Sending to channel message hello, function handleMessage
    // must handle "hello" message and print to stdout.
    mchan <- "hello"

    // function handleMessage() must print "world" message.
    mchan <- "world"
}
```

Как я могу это сделать? В этом и суть, чтоб не запускать по сто раз функцию handleMessage() для обработки сообщения, а запустить один раз, в отдельном потоке и обрабатывать сообщения, является вообще ли это возможным?

Comment: Что значит «не работает»? Вы в курсе, что вы не ждёте, пока второе сообщение обработается?

Comment: @Ainar-G можете пожалуйста привести пример, потому что я абсолютно не понимаю что делать

Comment: Я до сих пор не понимаю, чего вы хотите, но вот вам кусок кода для медитации: https://play.golang.org/p/pf1VBXgQR4K.

Comment: @Ainar-G этот пример это то что я хотел! Спасибо!